# How to have user input in an if statement have multiple right answers

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I'm trying to make a code where a user can input their percentage grade and they will receive a letter grade. I printed out the scale at the top of the code and then I have a button where the user would click to start the function. I want the code to give the user a letter grade if they type in a percentage in the user input and have the `if` statement include all values that will satisfy it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var q1 = prompt("Please enter your percentage grade: ");
  if (q1 <= 100 && grade > 90) {
    alert("You have an A");
  }
  if (q1 <= 89 && grade > 80) {
    alert("You have a B");
  }
  if (q1 <= 79 && grade > 70) {
    alert("You have a C");
  }
  if (q1 <= 69 && grade > 60) {
    alert("You have a D");
  }
  if (q1 <= 59 && grade > 50) {
    alert("You have an E");
  }
  if (q1 > 50) {
    alert("You have an F");
  } else {
    alert("Broken")
  }
}

var q2 = prompt("Would you like to enter another grade? (Please type Yes or No) ");
if (q2 == Yes) {
  // This is where the loop would go
} else() {
  break

}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>
    Grade Scale
  </h1>
  <p1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>100-90</td>
        <td>89-80</td>
        <td>79-70</td>
        <td>69-60</td>
        <td>59-50</td>
        <td>
          < 50 </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p1>
  <p2>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here To See Your Conversion!</button>
  </p2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't both comparisons involve `q1`? Where does `grade` come from?

Comment: Also the last test should be `<` not `>`

Comment: Also the `q2` test should be `"Yes"` not `Yes`

Comment: If you would use `else if` you could omit half of the comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `else if` to ensure that the alert only happens once and returns only the desired letter grade.

```
  if (q1 >= 90) {
    alert("You have an A");
  }
  else if (q1 >= 80) {
    alert("You have a B");
  }
  else if (q1 >= 70) {
    alert("You have a C");
  }
  else if (q1 >= 60) {
    alert("You have a D");
  }
  else if (q1 >= 50) {
    alert("You have an E");
  }
  else if (q1 < 50) {
    alert("You have an F");
  }
  else {
    alert("Broken")
  }
```

It is also a good idea to validate at the top to catch invalid entries etc.

```
if (q1 < 0 || q1 > 100) {
  alert("Invalid percentage entered.");
} else if ...
```